# Create a json file using jq and multiple variables

Tags: arguments, jq

I have a json file like this:

```
{
  "name": "Job",
  "type": "xdb",
  "typeLogoUrl": "public/app/plugins/logo.svg",
  "access": "proxy",
  "url": "http://xdb:80",
  "password": {},
  "user": "xx",
  "database": "Job",
  "basicAuth": true,
  "basicAuthUser": "xx",
  "basicAuthPassword": {},
  "withCredentials": true,
  "isDefault": false,
  "jsonData": {},
  "secureJsonFields": null
}
```

Now all I want is to pass environment variables to key password and basicAuthPassword and to generate new json file as below:

```
{
  "name": "Job",
  "type": "xdb",
  "typeLogoUrl": "public/app/plugins/logo.svg",
  "access": "proxy",
  "url": "http://xdb:80",
  "password": "password" ,
  "user": "xx",
  "database": "Job",
  "basicAuth": true,
  "basicAuthUser": "xx",
  "basicAuthPassword": "password",
  "withCredentials": true,
  "isDefault": false,
  "jsonData": {},
  "secureJsonFields": null
}
```

I have tried like below to replace at least one key and it's giving me null.

```
/usr/local/bin/jq -n --arg "password" '.password = $arg' < input.json
```

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: It's giving `null` because you are using the `-n` command-line option.

Answer (score 1):

Security wise, it's a bad idea to pass password in command line, but I hope you know what you're doing.

Assuming that, you need to modify your `jq` command like this:

```
jq --arg p "password" '.password = $p | .basicAuthPassword =  $p' < input.json
```

Comment: I know that it's riss, but this command is going to run during the runtime where it will take the password from the environment variable which is in secret of my docker configuration. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the password is already an environment variable (which may not be such a good idea though), then to avoid exposing it on the command-line, you could use the `env` builtin, along the lines of:

```
.password = env.password
```

etc.

An alternative to consider would be putting the password into a temporary file, and then using the --argfile command-line option, for example.  Or if your shell supports it, `--argfile pw <(echo "\"$password\"")`